# Can't animate my div with margin left

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, margin-left

I want to have an animation, with a timer that scroll my div with margin left, but I can't even have a proper animation, when I try on my website, it just instant get the "-margin" and on the test nothing. Can't even get an animation when I copy/paste a working code. I don't understand. Here is my code :

HTML:

```
<div id="twitter">
  <img style="width:50px;height:50px;" src="mypicture">
  <img id="next_tweet" src="mypicture">
  <img id="next_tweet" src="mypicture">

</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0rc1.js"></script>
```

CSS :

```
#twitter {
  width: 1000%;
  padding: 95px 0 0 400px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 220px;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-delay: 2s;
}

#next_tweet {
  margin-left: 65px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

JavaScript :

```
jQuery(document).ready(

  function(){
            jQuery('#twitter').animate({
                marginLeft : "-1060px"
            },1000);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sqs7btcx/1/

[just want my div going from right to left, all 5 secondes if possible]

if someone can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code was not running on JSFiddle because it requires a `https` request to external files.

Secondly, your CSS has a transition delay which was causing your animate function not to run correctly.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqs7btcx/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#twitter').animate({
      marginLeft: "-=115px"
    }, 5000);
  });
```

```css
#twitter {
  width: 1000%;
  padding: 95px 0 0 400px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 220px;
}

#next_tweet {
  margin-left: 65px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="twitter">
  <img style="width:50px;height:50px;" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/10/1425504302-kancolle-9.png">
  <img id="next_tweet" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/10/1425504302-kancolle-9.png">
  <img id="next_tweet" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/10/1425504302-kancolle-9.png">
  <img id="next_tweet" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/10/1425504302-kancolle-9.png">
  <img id="next_tweet" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/10/1425504302-kancolle-9.png">
  <img id="next_tweet" src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/10/1425504302-kancolle-9.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask what is the function to use if I want the div to go 5 times left(for example), and then going back at the first margin ?

Comment: oh sry, no more question, with the changes my old code work for that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use js lib: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(

  function(){
            jQuery('#twitter').animate({
                marginLeft : "-1060px"
            },1000);

});
</script>
```

Comment: If you read his code, you'll see jQuery is already being loaded.

Comment: Its work for me when i remove http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0rc1.js, and use https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js